# Conditional Joint distribution decomposition

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, independence

Let $I$ be an index set and $\mathcal{X}_i$ for $i\in I$ be a standard measurable space (or say a Polish space or $\mathbb{R}$). Suppose that the probability measure $P(X_I)$ on the product space $\mathcal{X}_I:=\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal{X}_i $ can be decomposed into independent components, i.e., $P(X_I)=\bigotimes_{i\in I}P(X_i)$. Let $f:\mathcal{X}_I\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ be a measurable mapping. Given a measurable subset $E\subseteq \mathcal{Y}$ such that $P(X_I\in f^{-1}(E))>0$. Now we can decompose the conditional probability measure $P(X_I\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))$ into the form $$P(X_I\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))=P(X_{B_1}\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))\otimes\cdots\otimes P(X_{B_n}\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))\otimes \bigotimes_{i\in I\setminus B_0}P(X_i),$$
where $B_1,\ldots,B_n\subseteq I$ and $B_0=I\setminus\dot{\cup}_{i=1}^{n}B_i$ ($\dot{\cup}$ means disjoint union) are the finest disjoint decomposition of $I$ in the sense that:

1. we have $P(X_{i_1},X_{i_2}\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))=P(X_{i_1}\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))\otimes P(X_{i_2}\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))$ for $i_1\in B_{j_1}$ and $i_2\in B_{j_2}$ with $j_1\ne j_2$ (if e.g., $j_1=0$ then we replace $P(X_{j_1}\mid X_I\in f^{-1}(E))$ by  $P(X_{j_1}))$;
2. for $i_1,i_2\in B_j$ with $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have that $X_{i_1}$ and $X_{i_2}$ are dependent given $X_I\in f^{-1}(E)$.

Now my question is: Is there an elegant way to characterize the sets $B_0,B_1,\ldots,B_n$ via $P(X_I)$, $f$ and $E$?

For example, I tried to characterize $B_0$ as $\tilde{B}_0=\{i\in I\mid \exists g:\mathcal{X}_{I\setminus \{i\}}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y} \text{ such that } f(x_I)=g(x_{I\setminus\{i\}})\ P(X_I)\text{-a.s.}\}$. I can show that if $i_i,i_2\in \tilde{B}_0$ then we have that $X_{i_1}$ and $X_{i_2}$ are independent given $X_I\in f^{-1}(E)$ but not the other way around. Is there an if-and-only-if characterization of $B_0$ and also other $B_i$'s?